# fs -put (or copyFromLocal) and data type awareness

Tags: hadoop

If I upload a text file of size 117MB to HDFS using hadoop fs -put filename, I can see that one datanode contains a filepart of size 64.98MB (the default file split size) and  another data node contains a filepart of size 48.59MB.

My question is whether this split position was calculated in a data aware way (recognising somehow that the file is text and thus splitting the file at "\n", for example).

I realise that InputFileFormat can be used to tell running jobs how to split the file in an intelligent way but as I didn't specify the file type in the fs -put command, I was wondering if (and if so how) an intelligent splitting would be done in this case.

Ellie

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mixing up 2 things here, following 2 types of splitting are completely separate:

1. Splitting files into HDFS blocks
2. Splitting files to be distributed to the mappers

And, no, split position wasn't calculated in a data aware way.

Now, by default if you are using `FileInputFormat`, then these both types of splitting kind-of overlaps (and hence are identical).

But you can always have a custom way of splitting for the second point above(or even have no splitting at all, i.e. have one complete file go to a single mapper).

Also you can change the hdfs block size independent of the way your `InputFormat` is splitting input data.

Another important point to note here is that, while the files are actually broken physically when getting stored in HDFS, but for the split in order to distribute to mappers, there is no actual physical split of files, rather it is only logical split.

Taking example from [here](http://search-hadoop.com/m/R08GlLTWYb) :

> Suppose we want to load a 110MB text file to hdfs. hdfs block size and
>   Input split size is set to 64MB.
>
> 1. Number of mappers is based on number of Input splits not number of hdfs block splits.
> 2. When we set hdfs block to 64MB, it is exactly 67108864(64*1024*1024) bytes. I mean it doesn't matter the file will
>      be split from middle of the line.
> 3. Now we have 2 input split (so two maps). Last line of first block and first line of second block is not meaningful. TextInputFormat is
>      responsible for reading meaningful lines and giving them to map jobs.
>      What TextInputFormat does is:
>
>    - In second block it will seek to second line which is a complete line    and read from there and gives it to second mapper.
>    - First mapper will read until the end of first block and also it will    process the (last incomplete line of first block + first
>        incomplete line of    second block).

Read more [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce).

Comment: Dear Amar, thanks very much for the detailed and helpful reply! I had realised there were two types of splitting (HDFS split and mapper split) but what I didn't realise is that the HDFS split can (and will) be overridden when the mapper split is done by TextInputFormat. Such that, as you say, it doesn't matter where the input file is split as this will be 'resplit' by the TextInputFormat during the mapping phase if necessary. So you could have a case in which a mapper receives a block which is a combination of text sent from more than one node. Do I have this right?